# Проектирование Базы данных "Расписание"

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть необходимость создать БД для составления расписания и учета количества отведенных часов. У группы есть карточка на учебный год, в которой расписаны все предметы, есть какой то предмет, по нему проводится опеределенной количество лекций, практических занятий и тд. Таблицы для хранения карточки группы я уже расписал там все норм. Как можно реализовать в бд хранение остатков часов? Еще одну таблицу создать, добавить доп поля у таблиц в которых будут храниться актуальные остатки или еще как то? Как с такими ситуациями справляются?

Comment: Создайте таблицу с полным количеством часов. Остатки будете находить как разность общих и проведенных .

Comment: Да, посидел подумал уже к этому и пришел, спасибо